# Haskell: ignore a case or using when

Tags: haskell, if-statement, yesod

I'll still have a lot to learn about Haskell and I am having a bit of trouble with the following code. I can do the following, but of course it creates compiler warnings since not all cases are presented in `case address s of`, I'd like to make sure those warnings are not there:

```
postAddTenantR :: Handler Value
postAddTenantR = do
    newTenantData <- parseJsonBody :: Handler (Result NewTenant)
    case newTenantData of
      Success s -> runDB $ do
        newTenantGroup <- insert $ TenantGroup
        _ <- insert $ Tenant (firstName s) (lastName s) (Just newTenantGroup)

        case address s of
          Just newAddress -> do
            newProperty <- insert $ Property newAddress
            insert $ Lease Nothing Nothing Nothing newProperty newTenantGroup

        returnJson $ ProcessingResponse True Nothing
      Error e -> returnJson $ ProcessingResponse False (Just $ pack e)
```

I am not sure how to do something like `Nothing -> do {}` or `Nothing -> return ()` that matches the type. If it is Nothing than I don't want to do anything. I also thought to use `when` but again the compiler doesn't like the return type:

```
when (isJust $ address s) $ do
  newAddress <- address s
  newProperty <- insert $ Property newAddress
  insert $ Lease Nothing Nothing Nothing newProperty newTenantGroup
```

Comment: If you're not using the value from the `just` case, and it doesn't seem like you are, you could just do `void $ do` or something similar so that the type is `SomeMonad ()` and then just use `return ()`

Comment: The type of `when` is `Monad m => Bool -> m () -> m ()`, so it _cannot_ be used to conditionally return a value from a monadic action.  Could you potentially have a return type of `Handler (Maybe Value)` instead?  Or possibly you could return a default `Value` value?  It looks like you're sending JSON back, so you could just send an empty JSON document.

Comment: Note that instead of `_ <- x`, you would typically just write `x`.

Comment: @amalloy the compiler gives a warning if you do `_ <- insert...` probably a setting in the Persistent package.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that both alternatives of a `case` expression need to have the same type. Since you are ignoring the return value, you can add a `return ()` to the `Just` case. You should then be able to use `return ()` in the `Nothing` case as well:

```
case address s of
  Just newAddress -> do
    ...
    return ()
  Nothing -> return ()
```

Comment: Ah ha, thank you! I see what your saying, it interprets the return type from the last statement.

Answer (score 2):

In cases like this, I might use [`maybe`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Data-Maybe.html#v%3amaybe):

```
flip (maybe $ return ()) (address s) $ \newAddress -> do
    -- ...
```

(Though now that I look at that, that isn't the most readable thing, is it? Well, it's good for shorter expressions where you wouldn't need to use `flip`.)

If you're doing this a lot, you could make a function that encapsulates this sort of behavior:

```
-- suggested by jozefg in comments
withMaybe :: (Monad m) => Maybe a -> (a -> m ()) -> m ()
withMaybe m f = maybe (return ()) f m
```

Comment: Perhaps a simple combinator `withMaybe :: Maybe a -> (a -> m ()) -> m ()`

Comment: Small error, should be `withMaybe :: Monad m => Maybe a -> (a -> m ()) -> m ()`, right?

Comment: I like this way too. Nice way to do a one liner and looks very Haskelly

Comment: @MCH: Yup, I did mean to have `Monad m =>` in there. Nice catch.